# Phoenix: Error when refer to exq_ui dependency via git

Tags: reactjs, ember.js, elixir, phoenix-framework

I use exq and exq_ui for background job processing and monitoring in my Phoenix application.

At first, I refer to exq_ui in **mix.exs**'s deps like this:

```
{:exq_ui, "~> 0.11.0", only: [:dev, :qa, :stg, :prod]}
```

And it works fine.

But then I discover 2 bugs in the UI:

- When I click on the tab Busy, it blows up on the server side, and shows nothing in the tab Busy in  UI.
- In the tab Scheduled, when a job is passed args as a  list of map, it is showed as `[Object object]` in the column Args, instead of the real content of the args.

I fix those bugs here in this PR to the main official repo: 
https://github.com/akira/exq_ui/pull/89/files

But I cannot expect it will be merged anytime soon, so I change my dependency in **mix.exs** like this:

```
{:exq_ui, "~> 0.11.0",
  git: "https://github.com/chauhonglinh/exq_ui.git",
  branch: "feature/fix_busy_tab_in_exq_ui",
  only: [:dev, :qa, :stg, :prod]}
```

Now the trouble happens.

The `mix deps.get`, `mix deps.compile` and `iex -S mix phx.server` all run successfully.

But then  when I browse to http://localhost:4040, the UI doesn't show up, and in the javascript console, there are errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:4040/assets/vendor.css".
exq_ui:20 
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:4040/assets/exqui.css".
vendor.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
exqui.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

**Question:** Why did this error not happen with ordinary deps config, but it happened with deps config referred to a git repo?

How can I fix it?

*I think React and Angular also have similar errors in certain situations, but it seems that nobody has a good fix for them, just some anecdotes here and there.*

Comment: Make sure you have patched `0.11.0` or what your `mix info` shown, and not the `master`—otherwise, it might be an issue with what `master` brought.

Comment: I use the exq_ui `0.11.0`

Comment: Once again: make sure you have patched `0.11.0`. AFAICS, your PR patches `master`. Errors might come from the difference between their `master` and their `0.11.0`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: Oh, I see what you are saying.
So what branch on Akira repo should I point my PR to?

I don't see 0.11.0 branch.

Comment: No idea, sorry for that. It was just a wild guess.

Comment: There is no branch on Akira repo about `0.11.0`.
And the tags are only up to `v0.10.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. But I don't see any good solution for it yet if [my PR](https://github.com/akira/exq_ui/pull/89/files) is not merged (short of copying the whole exq_ui package and create a new one)

Here is the problem.

Referring to package like this points to binary distribution on hex.pm, hence it has all the emberjs and js modules prepackaged and babelified correctly:

```
{:exq_ui, "~> 0.11.0", only: [:dev, :qa, :stg, :prod]}
```

However, the referring to package in github points to source from github, so it has only source:

```
{:exq_ui, "~> 0.11.0",
  git: "https://github.com/chauhonglinh/exq_ui.git",
  branch: "feature/fix_busy_tab_in_exq_ui",
  only: [:dev, :qa, :stg, :prod]}
```

**Solution for dev environment:**
In order for it to work in dev environment, from within my Phoenix repo, I need to run the following commands:

```sh
cd deps/exq_ui/priv/ember
npm install
bower install
node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember build --environment=production
```

Then the web UI at http://localhost:4040 will work properly.

**Remaining Question:** When I refer to exq_ui from a git repo, I still don't see how I can make a binary distributed version for exq_ui when I want to release my Phoenix app.